# What are scope of python functions?

Tags: python

Is scope of a function is same as scope of a variable in python.
Like for example we have global, local and nonlocal scope for a variable, is there something like global, local and non local function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. A function is a first-class object, and can be bound to a name like any other object. *Names* have scopes in Python.

---

A `def` statement is similar to an assignment statement; it creates a function object, then binds a name to that assignment. For example, the following are very similar:

```
def foo():
    return 3

foo = lambda: 3
```

`def` is not indispensable, though, since there is no way to define an arbitrary function using an expression alone. (The body of a `lambda` expression must be a single expression itself, whereas the body of a `def` statement can be an arbitrary list of statements.)

Comment: **TL;DR**: **_names_** have scopes, not _objects_.